# Build Stored Procedure that inserts data into a received table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I built a procedure that receives a parameter with a table name, and inserts into that table, new data.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Ins 
     @tabela NVARCHAR(80)
AS
     INSERT INTO @tabela (CustomerID, CustomerPW) 
     VALUES (1, '123')
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SP1 
     @tabela NVARCHAR(80)
AS
     EXEC sp_Ins @tabela
GO

EXEC SP1 'CustomerPW'
```

But I get this message:

> Must declare the table variable @tabela

How can I declare the received parameter to recognize the parameter as a table?

Comment: You can't insert into a variable that represents a table. You either need to use if statements to select the correct insert statement, or use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, you need to use dynamic SQL.  You cannot insert into a string:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Ins (@tabela nvarchar(80))
AS
BEGIN
    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '
INSERT INTO [t](CustomerID, CustomerPW)
    VALUES (1, ''123'')
;
    set @sql = replace(@sql, '[t]', QUOTENAME(@tablea));

    exec sp_executesql @sql;
END;
```

Note:  You may not want `quotename()` if `tablea` could use multipart naming.